# How do I populate a drop down table using a list with data from a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my problem. I am able to populate the list with data from a single table. But I need to read one table, and get data from another table based on those values.

there are 4 tables:

- user (name and userid)
- friends (usrid and friendid), friendid is the userid of the friend
- accounts (acc_no and userid)
- transactions (from, to and userid) from and to are account_nos and userid is the id of the "from" user

accounts calls the new transaction method. "from" is a parameter given to the new method here. I am able to find the userid using this account number like this:

```
@account=Account.find_by(:acc_no => params[:from])
@transaction.userid = @account.user_id
```

This works when I print it in the view.
Now, I need a drop down list for "to", which should be filled with all the account numbers of the friends that this user has. For this, I first found out the friends of this user like this:

```
@list1=Friend.where(:user_id => @transaction.userid)
```

To test this, I just used this list in my view in this way:

```
<%= f.select :to, @list1.friendid %>
```

This also worked. Now, using list1, i need to generate another list which consists of all the acc_no/accounts of the ids present in list1

This is where I got no output. I tried this:

```
@list2 = @list1.map{|i| Account.where(:user_id => i.friend_id)}
```

This is not working for me. basically I need to perform this query:

```
select * from accounts where user_id in (select friend_id from friends where user_id = (select user_id from account where acc_no = params[:from]))
```

I got the 2 nested queries, but am unable to get the equivalent of the outer query working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try passing in an array of IDs:

```
list1_ids = @list1.pluck(:id)
@list2 = Account.where(user_id: list1_ids)
```

Comment: I am sorry, this does not work. When I try to use @list2.acc_no in the form, it says  "undefined method `acc_no' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>" even though acc_no is a column. The exact same code worked for @list1. If i do @list2 = Account.where(user_id: list1_ids).pluck(:acc_no), it just shows an empty drop down box